# GLException: No default device available in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, maven, jogl, jzy3d

Before getting the error in the title, I was getting the following transformException

```
Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/LICENSE
path\to\file\miglayout-3.7.4.jar
path\to\file\log4j-1.2.16.jar
```

I cannot delete either, because they are redownloaded by my maven dependencies when I build the gradle. I remediated the problem by adding

```
packagingOptions{
    pickFirst 'META-INF/*'
}
```

within the android section of my build.gradle

The error was thrown by the following block of code

```
    if(null==defaultDevice) { // avoid NPE and notify of incomplete initialization
        throw new GLException("No default device available");
    }
```

How can I work my way around this problem?

Comment: The two errors appear unrelated. Please show a [mcve] which reproduces the current error.

Comment: I already answered to his questions here: http://forum.jogamp.org/GLException-No-default-device-available-in-Android-Studio-tp4038031.html @Ryan Chrome Please refrain yourself from posting the same question everywhere, especially without making the effort to provide us the necessary information to investigate further.